# entry point script problem with pyproject.toml

Tags: python, package, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to create a python program that has an entry point script in `pyproject.toml`. However, I haven't been able to get the program to execute from both the entry point script for the installed package in a venv, and from the command line in the usual manner. The only way I could get it to work was to have two copies of the starting module file, in separate directories.

The directory structure is:

```
/path/to/example/project/
    ├── example/                    Python package directory.
    │   ├── __init__.py             This makes the directory a package.
    │   ├── start_module.py         The starting program module 
    │   └── main_module.py          The main program module.
    ├── start_module.py             Copy of the starting program module.
    ├── pyproject.toml              Definition of build process of the package.
    └── setup.cfg                   Configuration details of the python package.
```

and the `pyproject.toml` has:

```
[project.scripts]
runscript = "example.start_module:main"
```

`start_module.py` consists of:

```
from example.main_module import main_Module
def main():
    result = main_Module()
```

I can run this program from the command line in root directory `project/` using:

```
python start_module.py
```

and from the virtual environment where the package is installed using:

```
runscript
```

but I haven't been able to reconcile these two arrangements with a single copy of `start_module.py` in either the root directory or the package directory. I think I'm missing something about package imports but can't put my finger on it.